# Change model type to subclass

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My app deals with a ton of data that I call 'Subdata' (because it's a child of my real data and not independent). They all follow a similar format: they all have ids, a type and a pointer to the parent element. This all works just fine in Ember.js the way I have it now. The server has no notion of the type (just a field of the object), but the client does. I have different Ember.js models for each type so they can each have different properties.

My problem is that I need to convert from normal subdata to typed subdata. I could do this in my adapter and transform the JSON as soon as it gets in. But I found a more elegant way using the `filterProperty` method. I can just make properties that filter based on the mixed subdata array. Ignoring performance (which I'm not worried about), it seems like a much cleaner method.

However, the resulting array returned from `filterProperty` is an array of `SubdataModel`s. How can I convert those models to a particular subclass of `SubdataModel`?